# network share on external harddrive gone after restart

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, network-shares

I  want to share a folder to my network. I currently do this with rightclick on the folder and then settings and then network share (not sure what its called in englisch. the german word is "Freigabe") and then "Freigabe" again 2 times. Then I can access this folder from a different windows pc (PC2)in the network after logging in into the other pc (PC1) with the account from PC1.

This works until PC1 gets restartet. Then this folder is not accessible any more until I repeat the above process.

I think this might happen because the folder to be shared is on an external hard drive that usually only gets connected after windows has finished booting.

What do I need to do so that this folder is accessible after every reboot without enabling the network share every time.

Comment: "Freigabe" = "Share" in this context

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem as well. It has been reported by many users on many different forums. This is one of a few examples of it on [Seagate's own forums](http://forums.seagate.com/t5/GoFlex-GoFlex-Desk-GoFlex-Pro/Goflex-Desk-Not-Recognized-on-Reboot-from-7-3-2011/td-p/107912). They are insisting it is a problem with the USB drivers provided by the chipset/motherboard manufacturers. None of the proposed solutions have worked for me making this product extremely inconvenient to use on a computer that is not always right next to you.